# Does the voltage add up when the battery cell connected to 3.3V Vcc in series?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-protection

[image]

Hi, I am new to electronic engineering. The battery cell is 3.3V and an extra voltage source is also 3.3V (in series?), so I suspect that the voltage will add up to 6.6V. From my understanding, ATtiny85 is going to read the voltage value of the light resistor (LDR07) and microphone condenser from different pins and send a signal to the diode (LED) to turn the light on/off. This 6.6V will supply the microcontroller, the LED, and the microphone. What's the point of having a resistor after the LED and the GND? Are they for safety only?

Comment: `and Vcc is also 3.3V` where is that 3.3V coming from? Is your battery cell the only power source or extra/backup?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I think it's an extra power source with a battery cell.

Comment: Please unambiguously indicate where the extra voltage source is.

Comment: @Andyaka In general, this kind of power symbol is to indicate where the node has its voltage value? I think I misinterpreted the symbol and thought there is an extra source.

Answer (score 0):

You interpret this wrong. In the schematics the battery is the sole source of power for the circuit. The power symbol of +3.3V is just to visualize a power net of 3.3V, it's not a power source in itself.

The resistor will lower the current for the LED, otherwise it will die.

Comment: In general, this kind of power symbol is to indicate where the node has its voltage value? The resistor prevents a high current from flowing back to the diode?

Comment: @Sum  The 3V3 symbol means that THE BATTERY supplies a nominal 3V3 to this point. ||There is no other energy source so no current can flow from anywhere except from the battery. || The resistor helps control how much current flows via the path: Battery - ATTiny - PB1 - LED - Resistor - Ground . || I LED ~= [V_PB1 - VfLED] / LED_Resistor